# Access rights through database table

Tags: c#, security, asp.net, login

I made a login system with access rights (ASP.NET WebForm) and I store the info's in a database table. I don't use the built in feature of asp.net like Forms authentication and webconfig. My question is, am I doing good?

I check from the database table if a certain user has access to a certain web page and if not I redirect him to another page/ error page informing him/her access denied.

Please let me hear your opinion/advise suggestion if I am doing alright or I should use the built in feature of ASP.NET Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use the Built-in feature if you're a new to ASP.NET, but if you're familiar with it, you can write your own authentication procedures. But do understand that those built-in features were tested by many people and they have fixed all(atleast 90%) of the possible vulnerabilities and exploits.

I'm not discouraging you. Just be careful when you're developing on your own.

Hope this helps :)